# I want to use my java's Jar file in my flutter application, what are the possible ways to implement?

Tags: java, flutter

I'm working on flutter application and i want to use the jar file of java in my flutter project, How can I import the 'jar' file in the project from android studio and use the jar utilities in my project.

Comment: see [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)